# Table name is a variable from same query (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, syntax

NOTE: I am aware of SQL injection possibilities, etc.  This question is theoretical.

Lets say a user queries a page on a server, getListOfPeople.php, and sends their user ID as a post parameter.

The php page contains the following (simplified pseudo code):

```
$UUID = $_POST ["UUID"];

"SELECT name, bio, photo FROM people WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT blocked_UUID FROM 'name' WHERE blocked_UUID = $UUID)"
```

Lets say the table *people* looks like this:

```
NAME     BIO        PHOTO
BOB      blah blah  o43987h2fdof43hr43h
SARA     blah blah  098u43jfewoijfwoiej
MARK     blah blah  re988cd9sc2h33hfddh
```

And the table *BOB* looks like this:

```
blocked_UUID
287364
387761
497745
329844
```

We want to give the people in the *people* table the ability to be invisible to certain users... so they simply add those unwanted users to their own table containing their list of blocked user IDs.

My problem is, in the query:

```
"SELECT name, bio, photo FROM people WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT blocked_UUID FROM 'name' WHERE blocked_UUID = $UUID)"
```

In the part that says, *FROM 'name'*, I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to use in order for that to work (querying a table where the table name is variable derived from the same query).

I would like to avoid entirely different ways of approaching the problem if possible, and stick to one single query.

Comment: You have to know the table name to get it. You could loop over the `people` table and get the names, then run separate queries within the loop. Seems taxing.

Comment: Do you want a 'name' to be a value of some variable?

Comment: well you can use local variables in place of table names: "SELECT blah FROM $var"   ...   the only difference is that I'm trying to use the result from the column, 'name,' as the table name after the WHERE clause.

Comment: It's not possible to do it in a single query. Table names are never evaluated as variables in SQL.

Comment: Having variable table names like this is horrible database design. Dynamic data should be in table data, not table and column names.

Comment: Why don't you have a single `blocks` table that has columns `name` and `blocked_UUID`?

Comment: Thanks for you ideas guys... Barmar... I don't know if I can do it that way because then I can't have multiple blocked UUIDs without creating multiple columns like: "blocked_UUID1", "blocked_UUID2," "blocked_UUID3"

Comment: That's not necessary. You can repeat the same `name` with different `blocked_UUID` values in different rows.

Comment: I would not make separate tables based on the name in this case. I would have a table with `name | blockedUUID` columns or something like that and enter the name and blockedUUID so you can easily query the results you want.

Comment: and if it has columns, name and blocked_UUID, then neither column is necessarily unique.

Comment: Why would it need to be unique?

Comment: @BooberBunz If you feel the need for a unique column, give it an auto-increment ID column. But you can also have a unique key on `(name, blocked_UUID)`.

Comment: ah yes I forgot about that!! (combining columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to have a single `blocks` table:

```
name    blocked_UUID
BOB     287364
BOB     387761
SARA    123456
SARA    232323
MARK    112233
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT name, bio, photo 
FROM people 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM blocks
    WHERE blocked_UUID = $UUID
    AND blocks.name = people.name)
```

Comment: doesn't the table need to have a column where all values are unique in order to work properly?  Sorry I'm new.

Comment: No, there's no such requirement, but you can always add an auto-increment ID column.